# The fourth order accuracy of $f''(x_0)$

Tags: numerical-methods

Could you please give me formulas for the fourth order of accuracy $O(h^4)$ of the $``$forward and backward$"$ difference methods to find the approximation of $f''(x_0)$?

Comment: You can find arbitrary formulas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences)

Answer (score 0):

Add the two Taylor series
$f(x\pm h)
=f(x)\pm hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)/2\pm h^3f'''(x)/6
+O(h^4)
$.

Comment: Please, I need the fourth order of accuracy : Forward and Backward difference methods for the secondderivative. What you wrote is the second order finite difference method for the second derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your efforts. I answer the question:

I used the coefficients in this table:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

The forward is 
\begin{align}
f''(x_0) =& \frac{1}{h^2} \Big(\frac{15}{4}f(x_0) - \frac{77}{6}f(x_0+h) 
+ \frac{107}{6}f(x_0+2h) - 13 f(x_0+3h) \\&+ \frac{61}{12} f(x_0+4h) - \frac{5}{6} f(x_0+5h)\Big)
\end{align}
The bachward is 
\begin{align}
f''(x_0) =& \frac{1}{h^2} \Big(-\frac{15}{4}f(x_0) + \frac{77}{6}f(x_0-h) - \frac{107}{6}f(x_0-2h) + 13 f(x_0-3h) \nonumber\\
 &- \frac{61}{12} f(x_0-4h) + \frac{5}{6} f(x_0-5h)\Big).
\end{align}